# Can't get Accord-FFMPEG-Package working in my .NET-Core-Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ffmpeg

I have an ASP.NET-CORE 2.1-Application in which I am trying to use the `Accord.Video.FFMPEG -Version 3.8.0`-Package. I've tried to install it via NuGet-Package-Manager as well as via the Package-Manager-Console.(x64 AND normal Version)

Installing works like a charm but as soon as I am trying to set the using-directives it does not work.

`using Accord.Video;` works
If I try this: `using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;` i get the following error.

[image]

.csproj-Files are set like this:

[image]

If set up for example a new `VideoFileWriter` there is no reference to the Accord-Package.

Is there some incompatibility that I am missing?

Comment: Same problem. No idea. Try downloading from github directly? I wonder if there is an issue with the nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Have you tried it with packages beyond the stable version?